# when joining 3 tables data missing for TSQL

Tags: sql

I am having problem when joining 3 tables (sort of).  I have a table inv with colums: invdate, invname, invqty, invaction.  action types as: add, remain, salvage

```
table data:
invdate,  invname, invqty, invaction
3/1/2015  pizza    10      add
3/1/2015  bread    10      add
3/1/2015  soda     10      add
3/1/2015  pasta    10      add
3/1/2015  pizza    1       remain
3/1/2015  bread    1       remain
3/1/2015  soda     1       remain
3/1/2015  pasta    1       remain
3/1/2015  pasta    1       salvage
```

current query:

```
select a.invdate, a.invname, sum(a.invqty), sum(b.invqty), sum(c.invqty)
from inv a 
join inv b on a.invdate = b.invdate and a.invname = b.invname
join inv c on b.invdate = c.invdate and b.invname = c.invname

wanted result:
invdate,  invname, added, remain, salavge
3/1/2015  pizza    10      1
3/1/2015  bread    10      1
3/1/2015  soda     10      1       
3/1/2015  pasta    10      1       1
```

result: i only get pasta, but not the others.  i am trying to have all  lines show instead of just pasta.  i also tried with left outer join and is the same.  it works fine when i try joining 2 tables, but not 3 or more.
what am i missing?  can someone please explain?  thank you.

Comment: You join inv as b twice. Where does c come from? You have bigger problems than the wrong data.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  The query is working correctly, but clearly not giving you the desired results.

Comment: sorry with typo.  changed query b to c.  i am trying to have all data show.  with names with no salvage, still shows 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want to sum the add, remain, and salvage amounts on each day.  (This just seems to be the obvious query to run on this type of data.)  If so, you can do what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
select invdate, invname,
       sum(case when invaction = 'add' then invqty else 0 end) as add,
       sum(case when invaction = 'remain' then invqty else 0 end) as remain,
       sum(case when invaction = 'salvage' then invqty else 0 end) as salvage
from inv
group by invdate, invname;
```

You can also use `pivot` and other mechanisms for this.

Comment: that's exactly what i need.  thank you.  what would be a good place to learn more on tsql?  can you suggest?

Comment: @JimChen . . . First start by understanding your problems.  Use sample data and desired results, not only for questions on Stack Overflow but for yourself.  Then there are numerous books, tutorials, and resources available for learning the language, but Stack Overflow is not a place to make such recommendations.